# Is it min-max aperture range on Nikkor Lens label?

Tags: lens, nikon

The label says 18-200m F/3.5-5.6G Nikkor lens. Focal length and G type are clear.
From the lens specs I see that min aperture is F/3.5 and max is F/22. 
So what does the label aperture range means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can aperture be f/11 on a lens with an aperture range designation of 3.5-5.5?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/how-can-aperture-be-f-11-on-a-lens-with-an-aperture-range-designation-of-3-5-5-5)

Comment: It's the other way around. **Max** aperture is f/3.5 and **min** aperture is f/22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that as you zoom the max aperture increases from f3.5 at 18mm to f5.6 at 200mm

Comment: and in specs f3.5 and f22 are both with 18mm(with minimal focal length)? Is it kind of standard in the specs?

Comment: Pablo, at 18mm you can set the aperture anywhere between f/3.5 and f/22. At 200mm you can set it between f/5.6 and f/22. If you are at 18mm, and set the aperture to f/3.5, then start zooming the lens to 200mm, you will see the aperture gradually move from 3.5 to 5.6 in your viewfinder.  If you start at 18mm and set aperture to f/11, then zoom to 200mm, it will remain fixed at f/11.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - Not true. The minimum aperture has a range too. f/22-f/36 on this particular lens (from 18mm to 200mm respectively) ([Reference](http://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/lenses/nikon_18-200_3p5-5p6_vr_afs_ii))